# onClick function used on dynamic content not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I hit a problem with the onclick function when i add divs with ids like "n_block"+(1-~). When I use the jquery zoom function on the objects to make them smaller or bigger onClick doesn't work anymore. I'm not really good at programming so the code might be kind of confusing.

Heres the code i use for the onClick of items:

```
$(document).on("click",function (e, ui){
    //When the document gets clicked, check if one of the items was clicked.
    if($(e.target).is($("#n_block" + cloneCount1)) || $(e.target).is($("#n_block" + cloneCount1+ " span"))){
        //Set current item.
        var item = $("#n_block" + cloneCount1);
        //Set style to current item.
        item.css("border-color", "Black");
        item.css("border-width","2px");
        item.css("background-color", "floralwhite");
        jsPlumb.repaintEverything();  

        //Check if key Delete was pressed while item selected & delete that item with his children.
        $('html').keydown(function(e){
            if(item.css("border-width")=="2px"){  
                if(e.keyCode == 46) {
                    /* Prevents line bugging*/
                    jsPlumb.detachEveryConnection();
                    jsPlumb.deleteEveryEndpoint();
                    var razred = getClass(item, "b_"),
                        id = item.prop("id");

                    item.remove();

                    if(razred == "b_2"){
                        $(".ovoj."+id).remove();
                    }
                    else if (razred == "b_4"){
                        $(".ovojLoop."+id).remove();
                        $(".empty_block_c."+id).remove();
                    }

                    if ( $('.objects').find('div').length == 2) {
                        $(".objects").empty();
                        $(".objects").append('<div class="b_s" id="start_block">START</div><p id="start_text">Insert symbols here!</p><div class="b_s" id="end_block">STOP</div> ');
                    }else{
                        /* Connects objects together with line. ****/
                        povezi(cloneCount, tip_crte, ".objects");
                    }

                }
                jsPlumb.repaintEverything();   
            }
        });
    }
    // If item is not clicked set this css to the current item. 
    else{
        $("#n_block" + cloneCount1).css("border-width","1px");
        jsPlumb.repaintEverything();
    }

});
```

And heres the zoom code for zooming in when button is clicked:

```
var currentZoom = 1.0;
$(".zoomin").click(function (){
    //Detaches the connections from item to item.
    jsPlumb.detachEveryConnection();
    jsPlumb.deleteEveryEndpoint();
    //Prevents spamming of button, animates the objects 
    $(".project").stop().animate({ "zoom": currentZoom += .1}, "slow", function() {
        if(!$(".objects").children().is($("p"))){
            povezi(cloneCount, tip_crte, ".objects");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** for binding events to dynamically added elements.

```
$(document).on('click', ".zoomin", function (){
    //Your code.
});
```

When you use normal `.click()` to bind event to an element, then that even gets bound to only those elements which exist in the DOM at the moment of the execution of code. Using event delegation, you can tell jQuery that we need to add the handler to every '.zoomin' element which comes inside a particular element no matter when it is added.

Comment: hm.. I don't fully understand how this event delegation works. ".zoomin" is a button aswell :/ Do I just use my onclick zoomin, zoomout and zoomcenter in this function?

Comment: @zidrrr isn't `.zoomin` a dynamically added element??/

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends when exactly is the script which tries to bind the events are executed.

For Eg: Lets assume this script is in document ready function of jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".zoomin").click(function (){
       //your logic here
     });
 });
```

Here this script is executed when the page HTML is completed loading into the browser. Now when the script executes it tries to find a element with the class `zoomin` and if found it will add a event to that element and move on. If the element is not found the script just moves on. So we should actually take care of when the script is executed and is the intended element available at that particular instant of time. If the element is not yet available in the HTML (element might come in later dynamically using jquery) we have 2 options to bind event to the element.

1) Execute the script when the element is being added into the HTML: Lets say I have a event which brings up a pop up with some image. Now I want to zoomin and zoomout the image. Since the image in the popup is added dynamically and I have control of when its being added, I can do this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.ViewImage').on('click',function(){
       // some code is executed which brings up the popup 
       // now we know that the image is added into html we can now run the script
    $(".zoomin").click(function (){
       //your logic here
     });
   });
});
```

2) We have no Clue/ Control when the element is added into HTML but still want to bind a event to it: This is scenario where we have no control on when the element is being added or not sure where it is being added from (might be from some external plugin used etc) or not having control at all on the element which is added. Thats when we use this syntax as suggested by @Rejith R Krishnan

```
$(document).on('click', ".zoomin", function (){
  //Your code.
});
```

This will work on all the elements which are in the HTML at the time of execution of the script and on the elements which will be added in the future with the class name zoomin. So this script can be placed inside/ outside of jquery document ready event

Comment: In my case user is adding in items that are marked with ids n_block1, n_block2 and so on. Then he can use operactions on this group of items. Operations like zoomIN, zoomOUT, zoomDEFAULT and if he clicks on one of the items, the item gets a black border. But if i click on one of the zoom buttons that change the objects( make them smaller, bigger, default) the onclick doesn't work any more. So i think i need to use the number 1 solution as i'm adding in new items, and because the event listeners don't apply if i change the items. hm... am i thinking this in the right direction?

Comment: Yes, and honestly I got more confused after reading your comment :)